# Bootstrap 3 input-append upgrade

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm upgrading to Bootstrap 3, but I just can't figure out how to upgrade my old input-appends.

I had something like this:

```
<div class="input-append">
  <select>
    <option>hi</option>
    <option>hi2</option>
  </select>
  <span class="input-group-addon"></span>
  <input type="submit" class="btn" value="valami">
</div>
```

Preview: http://bootply.com/75910

In Bootstrap 3, this is the closest I could get

```
<div class="input-group">
  <select class="form-control">
    <option>hi</option>
    <option>hi2</option>
  </select>
  <span class="input-group-addon"></span>
  <input type="submit" class="form-control btn btn-default" value="valami">
</div>
```

Preview: http://bootply.com/75912

If I remove that span it gets perfect, but they are in different lines.

Any idea how to do this properly?

Comment: Maybe you can use pull-left

Answer (score 86, accepted):

This is documented [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/6342) and [here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups):

> Remove input-prepend and input-append for singular `.input-group`. The classes 
>   have changed for the elements within, and require a bit more markup to use 
>   buttons:
>
> - Use `.input-group` as the parent class around the input and addon.
> - For text based prepends/appends, use `.input-group-addon` instead of `.addon`.
> - For button prepends/appends,
>        use `.input-group-btn` and place your `.btn` within that element.

Example:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12 col-lg-3">
      <form class="form-search">
          <div class="input-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control " placeholder="Text input">
              <span class="input-group-btn">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-search">Search</button>
              </span>
          </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

EDIT: Working examples from @kviktor and @max4ever:

http://bootply.com/75917

http://bootply.com/78014

Comment: Thanks, I only looked at the new documentation, the pull request didn't come to mind.

Here is the working paste: http://bootply.com/75917

Comment: Thanks this resolved my issue. What if we wanted to have space between the input and button?